# Compare columns depending on the value of rows

Tags: php, mysql, multiple-columns, rows

I'm  newbie to MySQL syntax, please help.

Updated query:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT  campaign, team, employeeName, shiftcode, scheduleDate,STR_TO_DATE(scheduleIn,'%h:%i %p')  as ScheduleIn, STR_TO_DATE(scheduleOut,'%h:%i %p')  as ScheduleOut, STR_TO_DATE(MID(scheduleIn,7,4), '%h:%i') as sIn FROM tbl_uploadedschedule WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT scOrigtimein, scOrigtimeout FROM tbl_shiftcode WHERE STR_TO_DATE(tbl_uploadedschedule.scheduleIn,'%h:%i %p') = tbl_shiftcode.scOrigtimein or STR_TO_DATE(tbl_uploadedschedule.scheduleOut,'%h:%i %p')=tbl_shiftcode.scOrigtimeOut )") or die(mysql_error());
```

But it returns nothing, dont know if STR_TO_DATE() dont function correctly with WHERE clause

Comment: Is there any reason you don't do select * from tableB?

Comment: What are the `Primary Keys` for both? Or the `Foreign key` for the other?

Comment: @FilipeSilva - yes i can do the select * in the tableB, i just dont know what is the right syntax for that. Also Table B has a string time that need to convert to time before i compare it.

Comment: @Edper - i dont know if having primary keys or foreign key is a big issue in comparing data in every rows that depends on the value of the other row. Please tell me if i explain it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `NOT EXISTS` like:

```
SELECT * FROM TableB
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT * FROM TableA
 WHERE TableB.Shift_Codes=TableA.Shift_Codes
 AND TableB.Time_in = TableA.Time_in 
 AND TableB.Time_out = TableA.Time_out)
```

See [Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70a18/2)

Using `STR_TO_DATE()`:

```
SELECT * FROM TableB
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT * FROM TableA
 WHERE TableB.Shift_Codes=TableA.Shift_Codes
 AND STR_TO_DATE(TableB.Time_in,'%h:%i:%s') = STR_TO_DATE(TableA.Time_in,'%h:%i:%s') 
 AND STR_TO_DATE(TableB.Time_out,'%h:%i:%s') = STR_TO_DATE(TableA.Time_out,'%h:%i:%s'))
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70a18/3)

Comment: Is there any way i can do that code with STR_TO_DATE() as my WHERE clause?

Comment: Whenever i use STR_TO_DATE() in the WHERE clause, it always returning null value. I dont know why.

Comment: Yes you can like if you want only hour, minutes and second, that is, STR_TO_DATE(Time_in,'%h:%i:%m') for example.

Comment: I already used you suggested code but still it returns blank data. I used STR_TO_DATE('col_name','%h:%i %p') for string format ("07:30 AM") to convert to time and STR_TO_DATE(MID('col_name',7,4), '%h:%i') for string format ("RD/OT 07:30") but still not working.

Comment: Please see my updated post above, its the actual query/data i have so far but still it returns nothing.

Comment: sir thanks you for, i already get the right data :) Thank you so much. Thats a big help.